# Bash unexpected EOF in my script to wget an archive and extract it, using error checking functions

Tags: linux, bash, eof

I wrote I simple bash script to wget an archive from iblocklist.com and extract it to my transmission blocklists dir.  After it failed to run several times I found that the .gz archive being pushed by iblocklist was corrupt but the .zip was not so I decided to implement some error catching and an alternate means of accomplishing the task.  After rewriting the script, I get unexpected EOF error and I cannot find where the problem lies.  I'm by no means an advanced user of bash but I can usually accomplish what I want through trial and error and google.  Not today.  I've looked for the obvious missing }, fi, and ;'s but it looks good to me.  Not sure if it matters but on this machine I'm running a Backtrack linux distro that more or less forces you to be root at all times.  I'm a beginner so please be gentle :)

```
#!/bin/bash

function test {
    "$@"
        STATUS=$?
    if [ $STATUS -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "error with $1";
    fi

    return $STATUS
}

function askyn {
    read -p "The operation failed. Try alternate means? [Y/n] " -n 1 -r
    if [[ "$REPLY" =~ ^[Yy] ]] || [[ "$REPLY" = "" ]]; then YN=1;
    else YN=0; fi
    return $YN
}

function cleanup {
    if [ $ALT == 0 ]; then {
        test rm /root/scripts/.lvl1/dl/level1.gz
        if [ $STATUS -ne 0 ]; then {
            echo Removal of archive failed
        }fi
    }else {
        test rm /root/scripts/.lvl1/dl/level1.zip
        if [ $STATUS -ne 0 ]; then {
            echo Removal of archive failed
        }fi
    }fi
    return
}

ALT=0
YN=-1
test wget "http://list.iblocklist.com/?list=bt_level1&fileformat=p2p&archiveformat=gz" -O /root/scripts/.lvl1/dl/level1.gz
if [ $STATUS -ne 0 ]; then { #wget failed first try
    askyn
    if [ $YN == 1 ]; then ALT=1;else exit;fi #prompt for alternate; exit if not
}else { #wget worked first try
    test file-roller -e /root/.config/transmission/blocklists /root/scripts/.lvl1/dl/level1.gz
    if [ $STATUS -ne 0 ]; then { #file-roller failed to extract the list
        askyn
        if [ $YN == 1 ]; then ALT=1;else exit;fi #prompt for alternate; exit if not
    }else { #everything worked first try
        echo Download and extraction successful
        cleanup
    }fi
}fi
if [ $ALT == 1 ]; then { #try to wget .zip
    test wget "http://list.iblocklist.com/?list=bt_level1&fileformat=p2p&archiveformat=zip" -O /root/scripts/.lvl1/dl/level1.zip
    if [ $STATUS -ne 0 ]; then { #wget of .zip failed
        echo Alternate means failed.  Exiting.
        exit
    }else { #wget of .zip worked 
        test unzip -o -d /root/.config/transmission/blocklists /root/scripts/.lvl1/dl/level1.zip #try to unzip .zip
        if [ $STATUS -ne 0 ]; then { #unzip failed
            echo Alternate means failed.  Exiting.
            exit
        }else { #everything worked second try
            echo Download and extraction successful using alternate means
            cleanup
        }fi
    }fi
}fi
```

Comment: FYI, in the shell, control constructs like if/then/else are not wrapped in braces.

Comment: Writing `test command args` is futile, since it is always true. The syntax is `if command args; then STATUS-OK; else STATUS-NOTOK; fi`

Comment: Try running your script with the `-x` option: `bash -x myscript.sh`. This will give you a better idea of where it's choking. Also, I recommend doing an `exit 1` or similar (instead of just `exit`) when you have an error. That way, other scripts which may call yours (if you ever plan on doing that kind of thing) will know if it failed.

Comment: No point checking `$STATUS`. The status is in `$?` (unless this is a bashism which you want to avoid).

Comment: Gah! `test` is a built-in; never define a function named `test`!

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  Sorry if I caused you an aneurism with my fubar script.

Comment: @jens Although the braces are not necessary, they are perfectly legal and can be a good aid to readability.  It's quite good style to use them, IMO (although the syntax is a bit picky).

Comment: The main reason I added braces was for readability but I suppose that indentation works just as well.  I'm not completely unfamiliar with the concepts of documentation, indentation and readability.  At least I'm trying over here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your use of `}fi` to terminate an `if`. The token `}fi` is not a `fi`. So the shell at the end of the file has a lot of open `if`s missing their `fi`s.

You are in dire need of reading the shell manual, understanding shell grammar, and asking your local shell guru. The script as written is fubar, even with the syntax errors corrected.

Comment: Thanks.  That did it.  I culled the extra { } out of my if/then/else statements and it worked like a charm.  Maybe in version 2.1 I'll try to implement the `if command args; then STATUS-OK; else STATUS-NOTOK; fi` although I did play with the test function in a little test script and found `$STATUS` to be > 0 when trying to extract the corrupt .gz file.

Answer (score 0):

Using braces as you have is a slightly unusual style, but there's nothing wrong with it.  However, the shell is a bit picky about whitespace:

```
if cmd; then {
    : commands
} else {
    : other commands
} fi
```

Note the space between `}` and `fi`.

Also, you are working way too hard.  Instead of explicitly checking `$?` all the time and writing error messages, just do things like:

```
if rm /root/scripts/.lvl1/dl/level1.gz; then
    : # perform some commands if the remove succeeded
else
    : # perform some commands on failure, but DO NOT PRINT AN ERROR MESSAGE
fi
```

The rational for not printing an error message is that the `rm` command should have already printed one.  If all you plan on doing is exiting when a command fails, you can simplify things and just do:

```
rm /p/a/t/h || exit 1
```

and you can simplify even further by just doing:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
rm /p/a/t/h
```

By setting `-e`, the shell will immediately exit whenever any command fails.

Comment: Thanks William.  I'm sticking with indentation for my bash readability.  When in Rome...

Comment: Thanks William.  The main reason I went with a function was because I planned on eventually implementing logging and running the script periodically with crontab and it seemed easier to pass the call to a function and then I could just log $@ so I knew which command went sideways.  I cleaned everything up, took out the prompts for user input, implemented my log, and stopped overriding built-in functions and got this: http://pastebin.com/fy1fMCHu  please let me know what you think.  Thanks

Comment: This simple script turned into some serious overkill but I'm using the opportunity to learn a little more about bash scripts.